# Finding the amplitudes for an ODE

Tags: trigonometry

I have the given problem

$y''+y=0$

with IC:

$y(0)=2$, $y'(0)=-3$

Clearly, this gives the solutions:

\begin{equation}
y(x)=3\sin x+B\cos x
\end{equation}

However, I want to find also  the solution to the amplitude and phase angle shape and specify especially the angle-frequency *ω*, period *T*, frequency *f*, time shift $t_0$, phase angle $\omega t_0$ as well amplitude *A*.

Period: $2\pi$, angular frequency = 1, frequency = $1/2\pi$, and phase angle $\omega t_0=0$ for the sine part.

How is this found for this superposed solution?

Do I take each component by itself, that is the amplitude of for $3\sin x$ is 3, the period is $P=\frac{2\pi}{1}=2\pi$, but what about the whole function ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, thanks  for that Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(x+\sigma(b)\cos^{-1}(\frac{A}{B^2+A^2}))$, where $\sigma(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$, the sign function.

To prove this, consider that $y=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(x+\sigma(b)\cos^{-1}(\frac{A}{B^2+A^2}))$ is also a solution to the differential equation $y+y''=0$, $y(0)=B$, and $y'(0)=A$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. But how did you find that out? Even mathematica did not know...